# I'm not sure if this is affecting multiple sites (and I don't know a good way to test), but it appears that flagging is broken

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, flagging

Flagging a post always results in a message indicating that the flag comment text must be greater than 10 characters, even when it is. This might be more suited to Meta.SO, but until I have the chance to see if it's affecting other sites, I figured I'd post it on the site where I noticed the problem.

I'm in the office, so I'm (pretty much stuck) with IE7 on Windows XP.

Comment: Posting here is fine. However, I can't reproduce the error. What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: @AnnaLear Sorry for the delay - I wrote this as I was waiting for some things to finish and posted without proofreading. I'm in the office on Windows XP with IE7. Given the one answer posted, it sounds like it's an IE7 issue. I've never noticed this at home where I usually run Chrome.

Comment: XP with IE7? Good god! For a stackoverflow guru like yourself, I expected that you worked for a more progressive place of employment!

Comment: @JimG. I might be able to get away with installing Chrome or Firefox, but some of our corporate sites and customer sites only work right in IE, so rather than having two different browsers, I just typically have tabs in IE open.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Possibly unrelated to the specifics of your question, but [IE7 is not fully supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/162704), and as the official policy is to support `stable` and `stable-1`, you might start experiencing other such little problems soon, as IE10 Platform Preview 4 was released back in November.

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox That probably is the answer. Could you post it as such for more visibility? At the very least, it probably means that this bug won't be fixed unless it's also appearing in some well-supported browser.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I have no idea if that's what causing the issue, IE7 is [not *fully* supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/162704). The (somewhat) [official policy on browser support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/56192#56192) is:

> We support current and previous versions (and possibly previous-previous version) of all popular web browsers:
>
> - IE
> - Chrome
> - Safari
> - Firefox
> - Opera
>
> Where "popular" means "has some reasonable amount of market share".

So, right now IE8 (previous) and IE9 (current stable) are the versions officially supported, and IE7 specific issues will probably never be resolved.

As IE10 Platform Preview 4 was released in November, I think you should start considering browsing StackExchange with Chrome or Safari, since I'm guessing you have a pretty good reason to not upgrade IE.

Answer (score 0):

At the office, I'm stuck using IE7 (all other browsers are banned by group policy).

I was trying to flag [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/124028/is-big-nerd-ranch-or-aboutobjects-ios-training-worth-it/129583), but am unable to do so. Flagging it for "it needs moderator attention" sometimes gives me 1, and sometimes 3 options. Typing in the "other" box gives the same message that Thomas is reporting.

Issue: too many first time posters, all within an hour of each other, praising "About Objects". They might be legit, but it looks like an astroturf situation. I voted to close the thread, and tried to flag the post for mod approval, then tried to flag some of the answers as spam, but not everything seemed to work.

Comment: FWIW, that question is cleaned up now.